# PHP / MySQL returning variable incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to figure this out and I am hopelessly stuck. I have a column named type in my MySQL database. It contains all 1's. In the below function `$row[type]` always returns a 2 in the while loop and I just can't figure out why.

Can someone smarter than me explain under what circumstances that could ever happen. I know it is 1 in the database but it comes up a 2 here and I'm sure I'm missing something basic but I'm new to this and just trying to write my own functions for the first time. Everything else in this function works great and just not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
function getQuestionsVendorForm($dbh, $hosp)
{
    $sql1 = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM sub_questions
    WHERE hospital_id = :hosp
    ');
    $sql1->bindValue('hosp', $hosp);
    $sql1->execute();
    $num_rows = $sql1->fetchcolumn();
    $sql      = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT * 
    FROM sub_questions
    WHERE hospital_id = :hosp
    ');
    $sql->bindValue('hosp', $hosp);
    $sql->execute();
    $question_table = '';
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        $isOdd = true;
        while (($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {

            if ($isOdd) {
                $question_table .= '<div>';
            }
            if (!$isOdd) {
                $question_table .= '<div>';
            }
            $question_table .= "<label class='dontend'>${row[question]}</label>";
            if ($row['type'] = "2") {
                $question_table .= "<input type='radio' name='quest_$row[question_id]'  value='Yes'>Yes";
                $question_table .= "<input type='radio' name='quest_$row[question_id]'  value='No'>No";
            } else {
                $question_table .= "<textarea name='quest_$row[question_id]' rows='1' id=''></textarea>";
            }
            $question_table .="$row[type]";
            $question_table .= '</div>';
            $isOdd = !$isOdd;
        }
        ;
    } else {
        $question_table = '';
        $question_table .= '<div>';
        $question_table .= 'No additional questions have been added by this hospital.';
        $question_table .= '</div>';
    }
    ;
    return $question_table;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row['type'] = "2"`

`=` is assignment, you want `==` for comparison.  When you hit that line the variable is being assigned the value.

You can also get in the workaround habit of putting the literal first:

`"2" = $row['type']` is invalid since you can't assign to a literal so you get an error rather than unexpected behavior.  This reminds you to use `==`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really, a downvote for that? I thought this site was for coding help? Sorry if I'm not the best programmer. Trying to get better.

Comment: Don't take offense for the downvote.  I'd also vote the question to be closed as it is too localized and not likely to help anyone else in the future (I'm sure there have been many questions here with the same problem).  It reflects the questions usefulness to the community at large and not the quality of the question or code.